# Найти уравнение расшифровки

Tags: javascript, шифрование

Здравствуйте. Есть такой код циклического сдвига текста:

```js
  X = 'Защита информации шифрованием';  
  n = X.length; Y = "";
  a = 15; b = 5; // Ключ шифра
  document.write('X = ' + X)  // Печать текста Х
  document.write('Y = ') 
  for (i=0; i<n; i++){
  j = (a*i+b) % n 
Y += X.charAt(j);
 document.write(X.charAt(j)) } // Печать шифртекста
```

Выводит всё отлично:

> X = Защита информации шифрованием Y = аф рионвфаонримеамцЗиаищ ишти

Только как теперь найти уравнение расшифровки, чтобы то, что вышло раскодировать обратно?

Comment: Это же [аффинный шифр](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80). Ты не знаешь, какой алгоритм используешь для шифрования, что ли? На вики все формулы есть.

Comment: Тут не совсем аффинный шифр. В аффинном есть x, что соответствует коду буквы, а тут сдвиги, кодов никаких нет.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = new Array();
 X = 'аф рионвфаонримеамцЗиаищ ишти';  
  n = X.length; Y = "";
   a = 15; b = 5; // Ключ шифра
   document.write('X = ' + X)  // Печать текста Х
    document.write('Y = ') 

   for (i=0; i<n; i++){  
      j = (a*i+b) % n     
      s[j]=X[i];
     }

     for (i=0; i<n; i++){
      document.write(s[i]);
     }
```

Comment: Как то так). X - это твоя криптограмма

Comment: Не пойму, в чём отличие формул? Знаю, что туплю, но голова не думает (тем временем решаю задачку с xor шифрованием)

Comment: Ранее вычислялась позиция строки, с которой забиралось значение на каждой итерации цикла. Вставлялось оно по порядку(с 0 до N). Теперь мы(за счет массива) можем БРАТЬ значения ПО ПОРЯДКУ И ВСТАВЛЯТЬ ИХ  НА МЕСТА С КОТОРЫХ РАНЕЕ БРАЛИ. Все просто

Comment: увы, у меня в задании написано "найти по уравнению шифрования обратное ему уравнение расшифровки";. Так что такой вариант не совсем подойдет.

Comment: В твоем уравнении: i-место символа в криптограмме, j-место символа в сообщении. j=(15*i+5) mod 29 (Наше уравнение - зависимость места символа в сообщении от места в крип-ме). Я не спец по крипте, но функция взятия модуля(%, mod) - односторонняя(найти аргумент по значению функции трудно с точки зрения  теории сложности вычислений). А тебе как раз и нужно найти уравнение i-f(j). Вот только это самое f - по википедии([ссылка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8F_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)) не найти.

Comment: Может я ошибаюсь. Но если найдешь другое решение - оповести, если не трудно.

Comment: Было тут решение, но сообщение стерто кем-то. Могу закинуть, но я умудрился зайти не с моего аккаунта. Попробую с моего